# How to use different percent values for guidelines in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I use constraint layout in my activity and I would like to set different percent values for my guidelines (app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"). I want to put this values to different dimens files (dimens-lands, dimens-sw600dp etc.) The problem is that I can't find any way how to put this percent value to dimens.xml. Is there any way how to keep different percent values for multiple screens in my res/?  This is how percents are declared - it is a float value:

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/center_guideline"
        style="@style/Layout.Guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer above does not work. It does not even show up in autocomplete when typing there app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="..."

Tried cleaning and rebuilding as well. Still no luck. Weird that it worked for you.

EDIT: What worked is changing the type from dimen to integer :

```
<item name="some_percentage" type="integer" format="float">0.6425</item>
```

Comment: It is weird, I checked it and it really works. I have no idea why it doesnt work for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I found out a way how to store value with decimal point (float) in res/values. It must be stored this way:

```
<resources> 
    <item format="float" name="guideline_right" type="dimen">0.84</item>
</resources>
```

Comment: Is this common in Android development? Or will production quality apps usually just hard code in different percent values for layout_constraintGuide values?